# Extract text between single quotes in mult line file with sed which matches given word

Tags: linux

Javascript file contains lines like below:
url: '/v1/api/test/123' 'x-cookie'

What I want to extract is text from single quotes which contains 'v1' word.

So output from above line should be => /v1/api/test/123

Tried below

```
sed -n "s/^.*'\(.*\)'.*$/\1/ p" <<< $name
```

Output given for this is

```
/v1/api/test/123
x-cookie
```

Output expected is

```
/v1/api/test/123
```

Comment: Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] a good question and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to the question and reformulate it (preferably with your code, the provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help. In its current shape, the question cannot be answered because it is not clear what do you ask.

Comment: You can try something like `grep -o "[^']*/v1/[^']*"` to select the lines that contain `v1` surrounded by any character except for `'` and to display only the fragment that matches the regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a string enclosed in apostrophes (`'`), that contain `/v1/` you can try a simple `grep -o`:

```bash
grep -o "[^']*/v1/[^']*" file1.txt
```

The `-o` flag tells `grep` to display only the fragment of the line that matches the regexp.

The regexp:

```
[^']          # match any character except for apostrophe (')
*             # zero or more repetitions of the previous (i.e. match zero or more characters except for '
/v1/          # match the string exactly (backslash, v1, backslash)
[^']          # match any character except for apostrophe (')...
*             # ... zero or more times
```

It matches a string between apostrophes that contains `/v1/`.